# SQL if Both the parameters are null then do not return result, if one of the parameters is not null then return result

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL if Both the parameters are null then do not return result, if one of the parameters is not null then return result.

Comment: It's really hard to answer a question with so little details. Help us help you - show some sample data, sample parameters, and the result you'd like to get for them

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when (firstname is null and lastname is null) then 
                 null
            else
                id
            end result
from mytable
```

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=770f9bcc732d3daf37d3377d34d4dbcd)